# GoogleEarth Engine layer in stacking with uint8 dtype changing values

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm trying to stack an NDWI to a set of Sentinel bands using the Python API for GEE via Colab.  The main reason for the NDWI as a band in a stack is that I'm resampling to uint8 and I've found that if I calculate NDWI from bands 3 and 8 **after** a resample down to a 0-255 range, I get pretty shaky results and the usual thresholds in the literature (e.g. `water = ndwi>0.2`) really fall through.

The GEE docs [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-addbands), would suggest that `.addBands()` will do the trick.  But when I try to implement that, the band that is delivered is changed and has values in a range of 0-5 instead of a range of perhaps 0-200 as I'd expect.  Oddly enough, I can calculate, convert to uint8 and export the NDWI band on its own without issue, but this creates more files to manage and GEE does not split up my UTM zones the same way for both the actual S2 images and the NDWI, so a gdal nightmare would be needed to clip the NDWI rasters to the studied S2 area. I'd rather have it all in 1 stack.

I tried:

```
#Use cloud masking from GEE docs to get a masked collection
S2r=s2_sr_masked.select('B8', 'B4', 'B3').reduce(ee.Reducer.median())
S2i=ee.Image(S2r).divide(NormFactor).multiply(255).uint8()#convert to 0-255 range to reduce download volume
NDWI=s2_sr_masked.select('B3','B8').reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).normalizedDifference().rename('NDWI')
NDWI=NDWI.multiply(100)
NDWI=NDWI.add(100)
NDWI=NDWI.uint8()
S2i=S2i.addBands(NDWI)
```

And that gives the odd behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Seem to have solved this with a simple addition of:

```
    newBands = ee.Image([NDWI])
S2i=S2i.addBands(newBands)
```